# Using tmuxinator to open a dynamic number of windows

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I would like to set up a tmuxinator project to open a dynamic number of tmux windows. In my scenario I would like one window per instance in an AWS Auto Scale Group.

I have a bash function to list the private IP of each server I want to attach to. For example:

```
$ prod-ips
10.X.X.1
10.X.X.2
10.X.X.3
10.X.X.4
```

I have a bash function to tunnel to any of those IPs:

```
$tunnel_to 10.X.X.1
....
works
ec2-user@10.x.x.1 ~ $
```

How do I pass the IP list returned from `prod-ips` into a tmuxinator project so that it will open 1 window for each line of output ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since project files are [first processed as ERB](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/blob/master/lib/tmuxinator/project.rb#L33), you could do something like the following:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/dyn.yml

name: dyn
root: ~/
windows:
  # just using `echo` as a POC; this is where you'd make your function call
  <%- `echo "111,222,333"`.split(',').each do |ip| %>
  - tunnel-to-<%= ip.chomp %>: echo tunnel_to <%= ip %>
  <%- end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @pdoherty926, the ERB syntax is what I was looking for.

Looks like functions defined in my `bash_profile` will not work, but if I write those functions out in the tmuxinator conf then it all works:

This works (the echo is the output of prod-ips consolidated into a single line):

```
windows:
  <%- `echo 10.250.XX.X1,10.250.XX.X2,10.250.XX.X3`.split(',').each do |ip| %>
    - ip-<%= ip.chomp %>: tunnel_to <%= ip %>
  <%- end %>
```

But this command does not work:

```
windows:
  <%- `prod-ips`.split("\n").each do |ip| %>
    - ip-<%= ip.chomp %>: tunnel_to <%= ip %>
  <%- end %>
```

But if I defined `prod-ips` long hand in the file the tmuxinator start command works:

```
windows:  
  <%- `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(has("SecurityGroups")) | select(.SecurityGroups | length > 0) | select(.SecurityGroups[0].GroupName | test("<SECURITYGROUPFILTER>")) | .PrivateIpAddress' | sed -e 's/"//g'`.split("\n").each do |ip| %>    
    - ip-<%= ip.chomp %>: tunnel_to <%= ip %>
  <%- end %>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Can we close the [related Github issue](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/341)?